# Whenever I click a link, It downloads an empty html file instead of opening another page

Tags: html, django

I am developing a Todo app with Django. I am trying to have some links in every task container to forward it into a detailed page of the task. So whenever I run the server in localhost and try to click on those links. it downloads empty Html files (with the name 'download.html'). I trided to figure if the problem is in the path of the URL but It turns out to be fine.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="edit-task/">Edit</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
</div>
```

I cleared the browser data like google chrome community suggestion, but nothing changed, Please Help me.
Do not worry! everything in urls.py and views.py is set correctly.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from taskapp.views import home, update

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name="home-view" ),
    path('edit-task/', update, name="update-view"),
]
```

views.py

```
def update(request):
    return HttpResponse(request, 'taskapp/update.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your view to render the template:

```
def update(request):
    return render(request, 'taskapp/update.html')
```